# How to use a Default "Select" option for a dropdown that comes under <th></th>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a dropdown box that in present under a "th" tag. I am using the following code.

```
 <th data-filter-control="select" data-field="Element_name">Element_Name</th>
```

where I am dynamically calling my Dropdown elements.

I want to display "Select" as my default element at the top of the list.I have tried with the following code. But this did not work.

```
<th <option selected disabled class="hideoption">Select</option>data-filter-control="select" data-field="Element_name">Element_Name</th>
```

But  tag is not supported inside "th" tag. Any idea how can I include this default "Select" option?

Comment: use `<select>...</select>`

Comment: Do you mean like `<th <select></select> data-filter-control="select" data-field="Element_name">Element_Name</th>` this? Or could you explain?

Comment: `<th data-filter-control="select" data-field="Element_name"><select> <option selected disabled class="hideoption">Select</option></select>Element_Name</th>`

Comment: Your answer generates a new dropdown box near to my Heading. I already have a dropdown, which I am defining as `data-filter-control="select" data-field="Element_name"` and also I am binding my data with that. I just have to add a `Select` to the top of my data.

Comment: What jquery plugin are you using to generate your dropdown as this is far from standard HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to use select inside the `th` like any other html tags, e.g. `<div>`, `<span>`

So what it should look like is:

```
<th>
    <select>
        <option selected="selected">Default</option>
        <option>Option1</option>
        <option>Option2</option>
    </select>
</th>
```

Where `selected="selected"` is the option always chosen at the start (can be moved to other options).

But I'm just curious as to where you got `data-filter-control="select"` from. Or was that for some other purpose?

Comment: Yes I am using a table. and one of its column name is Element_name and I should use a Dropdown menu foe selecting the Elements. And mainly I am dynamically getting the elements of the Dropdown list. So I cannot use Option1, option2.

Comment: how are you getting the options dynamically? With javascript or do you run a php backend of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you using a table. according your code i understand that you had placed option section between the th tags. you should use a select tags between th tags and use option section between select tags.

```
   <th>
          <select>
                  <option value="A"> A </option>
                  <option value="B"> B </option>
          </select>
   </th>
```

Comment: Yes I am using a table. and one of its column name is Element_name and I should use a Dropdown menu foe selecting the Elements. And mainly I am dynamically getting the elements of the Dropdown list. So I cannot use Option1, option2.

Comment: th tags use for table heading . where you can give your column heading too. and in next row  you can use the dropdown list. Your question is missing important information. what kind of technique you using to achive dynamically getting elements of the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this.

```
                <select id="paper-type">
                     <option>Please Select...</option>
                     <option value="op-one">Art Card</option>
                     <option value="op-two">Ambosh Card (Hard)</option>
                     <option value="op-three">Kraft Card</option>
                     <option value="op-four">Solid Card</option>
                     <option value="op-five">Ambosh Card (Soft)</option>                 
                </select>
```

To get the value of selected Item, use the JS code below

```
getSelectedOpt = getElem("#paper-type"),
                paperSelected = getSelectedOpt.options[getSelectedOpt.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: I am using a table. and one of its column name is Element_name and I should use a Dropdown menu foe selecting the Elements. And mainly I am dynamically getting the elements of the Dropdown list. So I cannot use Option1, option2.

Comment: @Vishwaroopa How are you dynamically getting the elements? Your question is missing important information.